# Como formatear una consulta SQL server con For Json

Tags: sql-server, json

Se tiene la siguiente consulta para exportarla a un Archivo JSon

```
SELECT  periodo, tipo, tipoDia, p
 FROM  registrar.tiempoPeriodo tp
 where frtID='hkt00010' and periodo >= '2019-11-10'
      and tp.tipo in ('ValorTipicoInicial', 'ValorTipico ')
      and tp.periodo = (select MAX(vers.periodo)
          from registrar.tiempoPeriodo vers
          where vers.frtID = ct.frtID
          and vers.tipoDia = ct.tipoDia)
  FOR JSON path, ROOT('QryTiempoPeriodo')
```

Guiandome con las instrucciones de esta [página](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

pero al tratar de realizar o llamar la instrucción sale un error en la consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sale incorrect syntax error near JSON

Comment: Que versión de SQL Server estás usando? Aparentenmente esa sintaxis está disponible desde Sql Server 2016.

Comment: @Asero82 la version es  SQL 2014

Comment: @ger Entonces la instrucción `FOR JSON` no está disponible. Puedes utilizar [las rutinas creadas por Phil Factor](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/producing-json-documents-from-sql-server-queries-via-tsql/)

Comment: @Asero82 a partir de que versión está disponible For JSON???

Comment: @Asero82 lo que me pasaste es para SQL server 2008, en 2014 no funciona!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al fin encontre la solucion para esto en SQL Server

```
Declare @XML   xml = (SELECT  periodo, tipo, tipoDia, p
 FROM  registrar.tiempoPeriodo tp
 where frtID='hkt00010' and periodo >= '2019-11-10'
   and tp.tipo in ('ValorTipicoInicial', 'ValorTipico ')
   and tp.periodo = (select MAX(vers.periodo)
      from registrar.tiempoPeriodo vers
      where vers.frtID = ct.frtID
      and vers.tipoDia = ct.tipoDia)  for XML RAW)
  Declare @JSON  varchar(max) = ''

 ;with cteEAV as (
  Select RowNr     = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))
        ,Entity    = xRow.value('@*[1]','varchar(100)')
        ,Attribute = xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
        ,Value     = xAtt.value('.','varchar(max)') 
   From  @XML.nodes('/row') As A(xRow)
   Cross Apply A.xRow.nodes('./@*') As B(xAtt) )
 ,cteBld as (
  Select *
        ,NewRow = IIF(Lag(Entity,1)  over (Partition By Entity Order By (Select NULL))=Entity,'',',{')
        ,EndRow = IIF(Lead(Entity,1) over (Partition By Entity Order By (Select NULL))=Entity,',','}')
        ,JSON   = Concat('"',Attribute,'":','"',Value,'"')
   From  cteEAV )
Select @JSON = @JSON+NewRow+JSON+EndRow
 From  cteBld 

Select '['+Stuff(@JSON,1,1,'')+']'
```

**Fuente:** lo encontré en en este [hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883243/how-to-make-json-from-sql-query-in-ms-sql-2014/39946937) en inglés